# Unix: Using expect doesn't preserve the stderr

Tags: unix, expect, file-descriptor

I am performing the follwing line from a unix server:

```
expect -c 'spawn ssh otherHost chown -R user:group /usr ; expect password: ; send 123456\n ; interact ;'
```

I am getting return value 0, an empty stderr and a stdout that says `/usr/... Not owner, /usr/... Not Owner ..`.

If I perform the command line `ssh otherHost chown -R user:group /usr` alone, then this message is returned appropriately with return value !=0 and the error messages in the error stream.

I need to know programmatically if there was an error, and expect (which I need to avoid passing password) doesn't allow me. (A good idea would be to use expect to create sshkeys, and then ssh normally to servers - but I need the servers to have passwords between them).

Anyway, how can I find out an error occured while using expect?

Answer (score 1):

I'm used to write all the Expect stuff in a script. This helps debugging and adds more readability.

In Expect, you can always add a "timeout" for each expect to handle exception. When the expect pattern is not matched, you can put some message to inform the situation. Take ssh for example:

```
spawn ssh user@192.168.1.1
expect {
        "Password:"     {send "user123\n"; exp_continue}
        timeout         {send_user "connection fail\n"; exit}
        -ex "$"
}
```

When none of the patterns are matched, Expect will run the `timeout` block and show "connection fail".

If I were you, I'd split the complex ssh command into many simple commands. i.e. ssh to the server first, handle the login process, and then do the chown stuff. The script would look like:

```
# login
spawn ssh user@192.168.1.1
expect {
        -ex "(yes/no)?" {send "yes\n"; exp_continue}
        "Password:"     {send "user123\n"; exp_continue}
        timeout         {send_user "connection fail\n"; exit}
        -ex "#"
}

# do chown
send "chown -R user /usr\n"
expect {
        "No such file or directory" {send_user "No such file or directory\n"; exp_continue}
        "Operation not permitted" {send_user "Operation not permitted\n"; exp_continue}
        "invalid user" {send_user "Invalid user name\n"; exp_continue}
        -ex "$"
}
```

Remember, in most cases, Expect knows nothing about if the command successes or not. The script must check itself by expect the output string and handle each situation.

For you case, I think there is a simple way to check the command by the value of $? if you split the original command into small pieces.

```
# after ssh login, do chown
send "chown -R user /usr\n"
expect -ex "$"
send "echo rv: $?\n"
expect {
        "rv: 0" {send_user "command successed\n"}
        timeout {send_user "command failed: $expect_out(buffer)\n"; exit}
}
```

Hope this helps.